# MYSQL Reset Auto Increment improve performance

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, auto-increment

I have a question about MYSQL databases will resetting the primary key improve performance? I use auto increment as key (NumID) see below but the count is in the 42 million mark now and lately I notice up and down performance. The database size is 8GB and there is 450,000 rows at present. I do regularly dump large sections of this database (old dates).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Count1` (
  `NumID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `MyUser` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MYitID` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `APICalls` int(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ResultID` longtext,
  `ResultIDtotal` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Time` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `iTime` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Record` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Notes` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`NumID`),
  KEY `MyitID` (`MyitID`),
  KEY `Date` (`Date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=42386041 ;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resetting the `AUTO_INCREMENT` will have little effect on performance. You would slightly reduce the storage size of the field by resetting.

A better use of your time is running `EXPLAIN` on your common statements and making sure you have a proper index wherever you're trying to select specific records.

Comment: The field, `NumID`, is an `int`—which occupies 4 bytes irrespective of value.  Thus storage size will be unaffected by resetting.